# How does Riemann curvature tensor make an appearance in the geodesic deviation equation? ("A relativist’s toolkit")

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, geodesics

How does the switching of indices in lead to the appearance of $R$ in the equation (specifically in the derivation given in "A relativist’s toolkit")?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Use the **Ricci identity**

$$\nabla_c\nabla_dZ^a-\nabla_d\nabla_c Z^a=R^a_{bcd}Z^b$$

[It's a good exercise to show that this is true for any torsionless connection]

Comment: Thank you ! I was just confused with the comma notation as soon as I saw  the more familiar triangle notation I realised it lol